# Adding and Subtracting Characters of Strings(Encoding / Decoding) in C

Tags: c

I was doing an assignment where I have to "encode" and "decode" a string by adding/subtracting a "password"(another string) to the string that will be encoded/decoded. However, when I run it, I get similar results to what the correct output is but still incorrect. I think it might have to with the way I am adding/ subtracting the two strings. I am sorry if this is trivial but I am a beginner. I would greatly appreciate any help!

This is the code for encoding and decoding(Note: I also had to write a function that finds the length of a string as I am not allowed to include header files)

```
int mystrlen(const unsigned char *string)
{
  int length = 0; /* holds the value of the length of the string */

   /* goes through elements of string not counting the null character */
  while(*string != '\0')
  {
    string++;  /* moves to the next letter of the string */
    length ++; /* counts how many letters there are      */
  }
  return length; /* returns the length of the string */
}

void jumble(unsigned char *string, const unsigned char *password, 
            enum CODE_METHOD method, int passes)
{
  if(method == ENCODE)
  {
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= passes; i++)
    {
      while(*string != '\0')
      {
        *string = *string + *password;

        string++;
        password++;
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= passes; i++)
    {
      while(*string != '\0')
      {
        *string = (*string) - (*password);

        string++;
        password++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the correct output:

```
Test0 ======================================
length of a is 1
length of b is 4
length of c is 0
length of d is 174

Test1 ======================================
Original phrase:
THIS IS A SECRET.

Encoded phrase:
xkstDl}AeC}fguouR

Test2 ======================================
Encoded phrase:
xkstDl}AeC}fguouR

Decoded back:
THIS IS A SECRET.
```

And this is what I got:

```
Test0 ======================================
length of a is 1
length of b is 4
length of c is 0
length of d is 174

Test1 ======================================
Original phrase:
THIS IS A SECRET.

Encoded phrase:
xkst ┴╛ô╡@╓àh1

Test2 ======================================
Encoded phrase:
xkstDl}AeC}fguouR

Decoded back:
THISD5° e1ocp!
```

Again, thank you so much!

Comment: You really need to show your full code.  I suspect there is a problem with how you are reading your data into memory.  You could debug this yourself by stepping through the program in a debugger, or adding code to output information at key points in your program to confirm whether certain assumptions you're making are true or not.

Comment: What is the `password` value you are using? When you add in a password char, it can cause the string char to go beyond 0x7F. That gets you into utf-8 territory. That is, instead of staying within ASCII range (e.g. 0x20-0x7F) you can end up with (e.g. 0x85,0x89,...) which would end up as something else (e.g. Chinese, etc.) This seems to be what you're seeing/getting. You may need to apply a modulus to stay within printable ASCII range.

Comment: @CraigEstey For these particular tests, the password is $#*!

Comment: What do you think happens here `*string = *string + *password; string++; password++;` when password is not as long as string?  You read memory past the end of the password - memory you don't own.  When you do that you get the wrong answer.

Comment: @CraigEstey I am not concerned with the ASCII values per say, I am just supposed to be getting the same output like the one above, and seeing that when THIS IS A SECRET is decoded and it gets a different result, to me that shows that something is wrong with the arithmetic involved, I am just not sure what part.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Oh, I see. So would I have to put a parameter on password by its length?

Comment: @CraigEstey  based on the expected working value they are treating this as extended ascii which means they aren't using a unicode aware terminal - for example a Windows cmd.exe command line.  https://theasciicode.com.ar/

Comment: @adsf What is the actual algorithm - do you stop adding when you get to the end of the password or do you wrap around back to the start of the password?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I just realized that the password has to be wrapped around so that it fits with the string.

Comment: Finding string length can be as simple as `size_t len = 0; for (; string[len]; len++) {}`. `len` now contains the string length (*note*: the string must be *nul-terminated* - as is required by all string functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your text string is *longer* than your password string, you are running past the end of password string (e.g. text is 8 chars but you only have 4 password chars). This is undefined behavior (e.g. random chars after that)

Here is some code that wraps back to the start of the password when it gets to the end. I just guessed that is what the algorithm needs. You may need to adjust this to match the exact algorithm/result you need.

Additionally, the `string` variable has to be reset to the beginning for each pass. Otherwise, only the *first* pass will have an effect.

---

```
void
jumble(unsigned char *string, const unsigned char *password, enum CODE_METHOD method, int passes)
{
    int pwlen;
    unsigned char *str;
    unsigned char *pw;

    pw = password;

    if (method == ENCODE) {
        int i;

        for (i = 1; i <= passes; i++) {
            //pw = password; ?
            str = string;
            while (*str != '\0') {
                *str = *str + *pw;
                str++;
                if (*++pw == 0)
                    pw = password;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        int i;

        for (i = 1; i <= passes; i++) {
            //pw = password; ?
            str = string;
            while (*str != '\0') {
                *str = (*str) - *pw;
                str++;
                if (*++pw == 0)
                    pw = password;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps tremendously. It makes sense now after looking it over. I was forgetting that the password needed to be looped and didn't even think of implementing it. Thank you!

Comment: Also just wanted to add that right after str = string is declared, there should also be a pw = password too or else it wont work on the second pass. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I wasn't sure that password needed to be reset on each pass, so that's why I commented it out.